# Usage of as... as

Tags: sentence-construction

> The negotiations are not about a deal as much as about buying time.

How to interpret this sentence? Can I view this as "the negotiations are not about a deal as much as it is about buying time"? "it is" is omitted from the original sentence. The sentence means the importance of buying time are more than striking a deal. Am I correct? Are both sentence correct grammatically? Are there other similar sentence structures like this?

Comment: "They are" (meaning the negotiations) is omitted, rather than "it is".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not so much [x] as [y]" (your example is recognisably a variation of this) is sometimes used sincerely, sometimes less so. Used literally, it means that it something is *less* one thing than another (so, it is both). But quite often it is used to suggest that something is not what it appears. The context ought to suggest what is meant.

Even though you haven't supplied any context, your example seems to imply the latter. I can't imagine any deal takes place without any negotiation. The statement seems to imply that one party was making the negotiations take longer than necessary, causing a deliberate delay in order to 'buy time' for something else. That could also imply some disingenuous behaviour. If the deal is, or is not going to happen anyway, then they may well be saying that the negotiations were not at all about the deal and were *entirely* for the purpose of buying time.